# Specifying random slope in a nested model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I am super confused on mixed models now. Can anyone explain me what does the following imply:

```
mod <- lmer(yield ~ year + (1|country/region/state), data = temp)
```

What I understand is that in the above model I am modelling yield as a function of time trend while controlling for the effect of location i.e. state is nested within region and regions are nested within country.

Now I want to include year as a random slope such that the year time trend varies at only one level i.e. state. How do I specify such a model. Is it:

```
mod <- lmer(yield ~ year + (1 + year|country/region/state), data = temp) OR
mod <- lmer(yield ~ year + (1|country/region/state) +(1+year|state), data = temp) OR
mod <- lmer(yield ~ year + (1|country) + (1|country:region) + (year|country:region:state), data = temp)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in your interpretation of the initial model.

Your first model with random slopes will fit random slopes for all 3 factors, so that isn't what you want.

I would use the 2nd random slope model to fit individual slopes for `year` for each level of `state`.

The 3rd model is interesting. On the face of it, it looks like it should be equivalent to the 2nd one, but I suspect that this will be dependent on the way the data are encoded to represent nesting (explicit vs implicit).

Comment: Okay. Thank you. The way I have encoded that data is there is explicit nesting i.e. state has ids that goes from 1 to 20. 1 to 5 states fall under region X1, 6 to 10 states fall under region X2 and so on. Same in case of how regions are encoded